# Markdown syntax highliter for Solidity

Tags: solidity, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone here know about an available markdown syntax highlighter for Solidity?

Pygments & PrismJS do not include Solidity, Vyper..

What does ethereum.org uses for its docs?

Comment: As a workaround you might try java or javascript, you will miss some things like mapping, contract, events, but the rest of the syntax is similar.

Answer (score 4):

" ```solidity "

Put your solidity code here

"  ```  "

Add 3 backticks at the start followed by keyword solidity, then solidity code and then 3 closing backticks at the end.